# Firestore query undefined on registration

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to run a Firestore query after the user logs in. The first time when the user registers it gives an undefined value but after a second login, the query works. Why is this the case?

Here is the code for getting a users interests:

```
const user = await store.collection("users").doc(props.route.params.user.email).get()
var likes = user.data()
```

This code only works on the second login. On the first login when the user is registered, likes resolves to undefined.

Comment: The code that's not working includes reg finishing.  Can we see that?

Comment: Don't just show the line of code that fails.  Help us by showing a complete reproducible example that anyone can use the observe the results as you see it. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example